# Random forests for multivariate regression

Tags: regression, multivariate-analysis, random-forest

I have a multi-output regression problem with $d_x$ input features and $d_y$ outputs. The outputs have a complex, non-linear correlation structure.

I'd like to use random forests to do the regression. As far as I can tell, random forests for regression only work with a single output, so I would have to train $d_y$ random forests - one for each output. This ignores their correlations.

Is there an extension to random forests that takes output correlations into account? Maybe something like [Gaussian process regression for multi-task learning](http://books.nips.cc/papers/files/nips20/NIPS2007_0431.pdf).

Comment: I don't know what you mean by nonlinear correlation structure. Should I assume that you mean that th response variables have a nonlinear relationship that you want to exploit in the prediction. If so that would be a multivariate regression model and in a parametric context would require explicit modeling of the nonlinear functional relationship. If there is a nonparametric analog with trees I am not aware of it.

Comment: here's what i've been able to dig up so far: http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/tree.html#multi-output-problems

Comment: Can you tell us more about your problem?

Comment: sure.  i have high dimensional "images" (actually dI/dV spectra) of peptides.  the goal is to figure out the locations & classes of the amino acids that make up the peptide.  

my first approach was image segmentation, but CRFs and pixel-wise random forests failed.  so now, instead of saying each pixel "belongs" to one & only one amino acid (not really true), i'm assigning each pixel a relative "influence" value from nearby amino acids.  this results in a $d_y$ dimensional histogram for each pixel.  hence, multiple output regression!

Comment: It might be a belated reply: in Crimisini et al. Decision Forests: A Unified Framework for Classification, Regression, Density Estimation, Manifold Learning they use RF in a way that might suits you for organs boundaries identification.

Comment: What if you did a SEM of RF multiple regressions for each outcome? Then at least you would not be ignoring the correlations / interconnected structures of the equations.

Comment: This might be late as well, but might help anyone stumbling upon this post. Random Forest can easily be trained using multivariate data. Everything happens in the same way, however instead of using variance for information gain calculation, we use covariance of the multiple output variables. And more importantly, the leaves now contain N-dimensional PDFs.

Comment: You should update the question to ask for sample code.  You should give dummy inputs and target outputs for the code that are something you can use for your work.  This will give you not only "it can be done" but "here is an example".  In my personal opinion this is one of the great strengths of MatLab documentation.  Those guys show by example what every switch in the inputs does.

Comment: I don't know that the RF "This ignores their correlations".  Given the ensemble nature of the RF, I think they might account for the correlations.  If they took univariate input and gave univariate output then they wouldn't be accounting for correlations.

Comment: Could you give a concrete example? My most common use cases for random forest are multinomial models with highly correlated outcome buckets, but I'm unclear if this is what you're referring to by multi-output. An example might help to clarify that and other questions for both myself and other folks. I also agree with EngrStudent; it seems like you're talking about a situation that random forest is actually well suited for, but I can't be certain since I'm not sure exactly what you mean by multi-output (multinomial?).

Comment: @Hack-R, This question was from a while ago, so I don't remember the exact problem anymore, but here's an imaginary example: say we wanted to predict where a peptide will end up in (X,Y,Z) after being subjected to some electrons.

It may be very hard to model the exact interactions so as to get a physical model of the peptide's movements, but we have some training data of various features of the peptide, various features of the electrons and its final position.

We could regress X, Y, and Z separately, but they should be very correlated, so doing a multiple-output regression is my thought.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example of a multi-output regression problem undertaken with facial recognition. It includes a coding sample as well, it should give you a start with your methodology. http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/plot_multioutput_face_completion.html

Answer (score 2):

There is a new package specifically for that (not personally tested)

https://cran.r-project.org/package=MultivariateRandomForest